# Determining the initial conditions on a set of PDEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I have a general research problem which is as follows:

Suppose I have a set of coupled PDEs, $ \partial f(x) $, $\partial g(x, y)$, with some initial conditions $x_0, y_0$

I can solve these PDEs numerically and evaluate at a particular point $(x_1, y_1)$ as $F = f(x_1)$, $G = g(x_1,y_1)$.

**I want to find** the appropriate initial conditions $x_0, y_0$, such that $F$ and $G$ are equal to particular target values $F_{t}$, $G_{t}$

**Does an analytical/numerical/algorithmic method exist for doing this?**

I can see a general method of choosing the initial conditions, performing the integration, looking at the result, and then perturbing the initial conditions somehow, but wanted to know if a 'smart way' exists.

Thanks

Comment: For an ODE there is a technique called linear shooting. For a PDE then the initial condition is some curve not just a point.